# set width of a rich column on the fly?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jstl

I'm trying to set the width of a rich column on the fly like:

```
<rich:column width="#{extraColumnWidth}">
```

where:

```
<c:set var="extraColumnWidth" value="#{document.instanceList.size() * 20}px"/>
```

But it does not work..i mean the width is not taken as it should but it remains the same
no matter how much size of the list is..

Do you know why?

Comment: tried in width too but does not work...if i print out the value of extraColumnWidth it's ok...it shows the correct value.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll leave this to the RichFaces guys :)

Comment: As per your solution, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: You can answer for yourself and get voted on it, unlocks a particular badge if you're interested in that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: my other columns already had width attributes and there was not enough space for my last column to be expanded:)